# How to get group statistics in Pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset looking like this for simplication:

[image]

```
lst = [
       ["2015", "A"], 
       ["2015", "B"], 
       ["2015", "C"],
       ["2016", "A"],
       ["2016", "A"],
       ["2016", "B"],
       ["2016", "D"]

      ] 

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =["Year", "Item"])
```

I want to generate some stats like the following. How can I do this using Pandas? My actual dataset has tens of thousands of observations, and many different items.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider running inline aggregates with `transform` and `merge` on a data frame of all possible values. Finally, clean up with `fillna` procedures:

```
from itertools import product
...
years_items_df = pd.DataFrame(product(["2015", "2016"], list("ABCD")), 
                              columns = ["Year", "Item"])

df = (df.assign(Count = lambda x: x.groupby(["Year", "Item"])["Year"].transform("count"),
                AnnualCount = lambda x: x.groupby(["Year"])["Year"].transform("count"))
        .drop_duplicates()
        .merge(years_items_df, on=["Year", "Item"], how="right")
        .sort_values(["Year", "Item"])
        .assign(Count = lambda x: x['Count'].fillna(0),
                AnnualCount = lambda x: x['AnnualCount'].ffill(),
                Percent = lambda x: x["Count"].div(x["AnnualCount"]))
        .reset_index(drop=True)
      )

df
#    Year Item  Count  AnnualCount   Percent
# 0  2015    A    1.0          3.0  0.333333
# 1  2015    B    1.0          3.0  0.333333
# 2  2015    C    1.0          3.0  0.333333
# 3  2015    D    0.0          3.0  0.000000
# 4  2016    A    2.0          4.0  0.500000
# 5  2016    B    1.0          4.0  0.250000
# 6  2016    C    0.0          4.0  0.000000
# 7  2016    D    1.0          4.0  0.250000
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!